# Phonosemantics: Doubts on the dimensions of verbs

Tags: semantics

[[Source:]](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf) p 13 of 20,  *Style* Stands Still, by 
John M. Lawler, University of Michigan

> [4.] -ɔl 2-Dimensional  shawl sprawl ***scrawl*** **wall** (Motion: crawl brawl squall haul fall)
>   [5.] -æp 2-Dimensional   flap clap lap map wrap slap strap **cap** ***chap***
>    -æk 2-Dimensional Connected   plaque stack bracket tacky ash
>      -ap Off 2-Dimensional  bop top hop pop flop (Separate: drop topple lop crop)
>   [8.] -mp 3-Dimensional  rump hump lump ***stump*** bump tump dump plump

Prof Lawler defines 'dimension' on p 11 of 20. However, I don't understand or can't imagine the difference in dimension between the verbs for 2D and 3D above. For example:

[4.] A scrawl is written on a thin parchment or papyrus; so the 'height' of the writing material seems trivial. So should a scrawl be 1D?

[5.] How is a **cap** 2D? Similarly, how is a ***chap*** 2D? Humans (including chaps) can jump, and so can move along the z-, beyond the x- and y-axes.

[8.] How is a stump 3D, but a wall (in 4) 2D?

Answer (score 2):

OK, lemme take these in order.

- Dimensionality is the difference between a point, a line, a surface, and a volume.
  Respectively, these are 0-, 1-, 2-, and 3-Dimensional images. It's geometric.
  Pretty much everything physical falls into one of these dimensional classes.
  And humans deal with, and talk about dealing with, physical objects and phenomena. A **lot**.
- A *scrawl* is a variety of writing. All writing requires (and thus implies) a 2-D surface to write on.
- a *cap* is a variety of hat that fits closely over the skull. That makes it 2-D.
- a *stump* is a 3-D object -- the remains of a tree that's been cut down -- that is roughly the same size in all 3 dimensions, like a *hump* or a *lump* or a *bump*. That's what *-ump* means.
  But *stump* also has the *st-* 1-D assonance like *stick, stem, stand, stiff, still*. 
  In the case of *stump*, the 1-D shows up, too; a *stump* is a 3-D object that used to be a 1-D object.
- a *wall*, on the other hand, is a 2-D object, pretty straightforwardly.

Since you seem very literal in your interpretations, I add that when I say something is "1-D", I don't mean that it lacks the other two dimensions, but rather that it has only one salient dimension. Trees are 1-D, walls are 2-D, and stumps are 3-D because **they** have (respectively) 1, 2, or 3 salient dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to improve my imagination. About *wall*, how is it 2D `pretty straightforwardly`? Its verticality seems the most important feature; so why not 1D? About *stump*, how did the cutting of a tree make it 3D from 1D?

Comment: @LePressentiment I wonder if part of the issue here is that cultural differences result in slightly different "prototype referents" for certain words. For example, I suspect that most American English speakers would most readily think of the flat surface on each side of a room when hearing the word _wall_. From your comment, I suspect that you more readily think of a stone or brick structure that divides two territories or serves to keep certain parties out of some area or to keep certain parties from escaping some area, in which case its height might be its most salient characteristic.

Comment: @musicallinguist, good point. When working for Sanyo I had to explain that a young colleague was off sick "after falling off a wall on his way home from the pub". This was greeted with incomprehension until I realised that the Japanese manager was trying to picture the young man falling off the wall *of a room*.